# Openstack - nova-billing

Tags: billing, openstack

I'm searching about billing in openstack and I found nova-billing. But in the github page of this tool https://github.com/griddynamics/nova-billing they use it with fedora or something like that. I tried convert the rpm file using alien in ubuntu and I tried install that, but I had no sucess. Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a open source billing project called dough which is developed by Sina.
You can know more from the slide:

http://www.slideshare.net/lzyeval/dough-openstack-billing-project